# Regular Expression for country code & Mobile No

Tags: regex

I need a Regular Expression for the following.
      I need to validate a textbox in which it is storing country code. It should contain a (+) sign at the starting and after that it should contain max 4 digit. So total including + sign not max then 5 digit. And in the other textbox it stores the mobile no in which there should be max 14 digit but even lesser than 14 are allowed.

I looked around the problem but can't find the solution to it so can you please help me out which works with both the different text box in a single regular expression as soon as possible.?

Comment: Have you make any code? Some jsfiddle??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex

```
^(0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9,15})$
```

[**Regex Demo**](http://rubular.com/r/InWk7DysBP)

Comment: What is the meaning of the syntax after ? i am not able to understand can you please explain it.?

Comment: It will capture the matches in first part of regex